# Framework for phone to desktop communication

Tags: c#, mobile

I'm developing a C# app on the desktop (Microsoft Surface like), and I would need to send data to phones (Iphone, Andriod, iPad, WP7 etc). The data transferring would pictures,text to and fro.

I'm aware of 32feet and Blueway, those are using bluetooth. I like to ask

- is there a framework which would allow the app to connect to the phones to transfer data
- is bluetooth the best connection method? Or are there alternatives

Comment: Should the transfer be initiated by the phone or the desktop app?

Comment: Both. We can transfer pictures from desktop to save to phone, and upload to desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the app to send to any phones nearby then Bluetooth will probably be the simplest option.

If you need to have some loginc and back and forth communication this will depend on the phones you wish to communicate with. For instance, access to the Bluetooth stack isn't currently available to 3rd party apps on WP7.

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing that I have to write a custom app for each phone, which I'm hoping to avoid.